# Detecting network activities of a Webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to detect or trigger an event of a web client but it is implemented such that you can receive page loaded or error events. I'm using a workaround to parse the contents by injecting a javascript method.

```
webView_content.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
```

But the event is called only on the page load or when a redirect occurs. I need to parse the content each time a javascript method is called or the state of the web content changes. This is required since single page design is popular right now and it is impossible to catch these changes. Is there any workaround for this like you can see the web network activities on chrome?